# Converting empty string to Char

Tags: c#

My application executes a store procedure from a webpage parameters list I have field in table which is char type now I have to fill that value from a dropdownlist which could be empty or it may have value.

I am taking that value as string

```
string productPreFix = Convert.tochar( drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());
```

This throws me error how can I convert the value to char and it also handle null if dropdownlist is empty.

thanks in advance for help

Comment: What value would you want if the string is empty? A `char` can't be null and an "empty" char makes no sense. It has to have a value.

Comment: Anything like null or to fill that char if string is null

Comment: What is "like null"? Besides, you are assigning your result to another string anyway? So why are you even converting it to a char?

Comment: no i am calling a store procedure and storing that in database i dont need to use that result for other string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
string productPreFix = new string(drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue.ToString()
                       .Take(1).ToArray());
```

Which will give you an empty string if the `drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue.ToString()` is an empty string.

Or:

```
string productPreFix = drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue != null ? 
                       new string(drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue.ToString()
                       .Take(1).ToArray()) : string.Empty;
```

If you need to check that `SelectedValue` isn't null as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to convert your string to a char.

```
char result;
bool WasSuccessful = Char.TryParse(drpProductIdFix.SelectedValue.ToString(), out result);

if (WasSuccessful == false)
{
   //stuff
}
```